# How to scale a button from right to left, android animation

Tags: android, animation

To apply left to right scale toa button i have used the following code. My button is in the right of layout. I want the button should start from its right X position and scale to left X position how to achieve this?

```
view.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to set the starting point to the middle right, you also need to set the duration of the animation like this:

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
anim.setDuration(700);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

in your case the Y start location is not important.

if you don't get it read about this constructor:

> **public ScaleAnimation (float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float
>   pivotYValue)**
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Constructor to use when building a ScaleAnimation from code
>
> Parameters:
>
> **fromX:**  Horizontal scaling factor to apply at the start of the animation
>
> **toX:**  Horizontal scaling factor to apply at the end of the animation
>
> **fromY:**  Vertical scaling factor to apply at the start of the animation
>
> **toY:**  Vertical scaling factor to apply at the end of the animation
>
> **pivotXType:**  Specifies how pivotXValue should be interpreted. One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
>   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
>
> **pivotXValue:**  The X coordinate of the point about which the object is being scaled, specified as an absolute number where 0 is the left
>   edge. (This point remains fixed while the object changes size.) This
>   value can either be an absolute number if *pivotXType* is ABSOLUTE, or a
>   percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.
>
> **pivotYType:**  Specifies how *pivotYValue* should be interpreted. One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
>   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
>
> **pivotYValue:**  The Y coordinate of the point about which the object is being scaled, specified as an absolute number where 0 is the top
>   edge. (This point remains fixed while the object changes size.) This
>   value can either be an absolute number if *pivotYType* is ABSOLUTE, or a
>   percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.

Comment: have both pivotXtype and pivotytype to 1.0f or (float) 1.0 and ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF