# Animation on a button android

Tags: android, button

Is it possible in android to click a button and then the button size change and take the whole screen is it possible to do that because i can figured how to do this

i'm tring this but it's not taking the whole screen and it goes only in one

```
direction Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation((float)1.0, (float)1.5, (float)1.0, (float)1.5);
        scale.setFillAfter(true);
        scale.setDuration(500);
        btn.startAnimation(scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can animate button with scaling. Use ScaleAnimation to achieve it on button click

[How to scale a button from right to left, android animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938798/how-to-scale-a-button-from-right-to-left-android-animation)

**Edit:**

You can use [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) for moving button to other location

Comment: ok but is it possible from the center to go to each corner to fill the entire screen ?

Comment: Yes you can. Check the answer